# DNN custom journal type

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am currently using Community DNN Version 7.I wanted to add a new custom journal type to the existing journal.Is there any way I can do this?If yes please provide me with some links so that i can refer on it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In 6.2 it really wasn't advised on adding custom journal types, that's why they added 32 to begin with.

There doesn't appear to be any methods that I can find in the API to directly add, so you might be stuck inserting directly into the database or create your own method to do so.

The table you want to add them is Journal_Types.

More information can be found here:

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Community-Exchange/Question/770/Journal-Can-we-create-custom-Journal-types.aspx

Comment: Hi Scott, have you tried to create your own? Ie. what happens if a module does not use any of the 32, as in my case?

Comment: Hi Rodney, you would use the standard status update if it doesn't fit into the other 31.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean we should not insert our own? (I did try this and it all seemed to work ok (I used ID 100 to allow for expansion).

Comment: It was over a year ago since Will made the statement about custom types - if you made it 100, I'm sure you would be fine. Other APIs that have since been added are fairly easy to extend, the problem with the journal API is the message is kinda hardcoded in the resx files, so it can be a little hard to extend for developers.